# How to read from .xls file using exceljs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exceljs

I am unable to read from .xls file using exceljs library. I also tried to read after changing my file in .xlsx using fs but still I am unable to read data from that file. Is there any way to read from .xls file using exceljs?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `.xls` and `.xlsx` are two very different formats, and renaming the file will not magically convert it. All you get is an `xls` file with the wrong file ending. exceljs doesn't support `xls`, which is the older, proprietary format. `xlsx` is an open standard and just zipped xml, which is easy to support.

Comment: @Aslam I am not getting any error or data

Answer (score 5):

While its documentation does not say it explicitly, `exceljs` only supports either XLSX or CSV:

- https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/148
- https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/165